# 20.04 with I217-LM driverversion=3.8.7-NAPI won't take address

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, ethernet, intel

I see the i217 on board NICs are highly problematic for a lot of people and I've tried the fixes listed - basically updating the driver (to 3.8.7, the latest as of this date) date and setting pcie_aspm=off and rebooting.

The card will not take DHCP, not a huge problem, but it also won't take a fixed address.  `ifconfig` returns

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::3bc8:75fd:5185:caaf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 50:65:f3:39:5b:03  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 18805  bytes 1537159 (1.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 476  bytes 114536 (114.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xef100000-ef120000
```

`sudo modprobe -r e1000e && sudo modprobe e1000e` followed by `sudo update-initramfs -u` with a fixed address (.17) yields

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.100.17  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.100.255
        inet6 fe80::3bc8:75fd:5185:caaf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
```

but pinging the gateway still fails:

```
ping 192.168.100.11
PING 192.168.100.11 (192.168.100.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.100.17 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.100.17 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.100.17 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.100.17 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
```

(that address is also unreachable/inpingable from other machines on the same LAN segment.)

Note that the NIC works fine under windows 7 (dual boot) and Ubuntu has no trouble with my cheezy USB wifi interface.

I've ordered a cheap Realtek RTL8111H based PCIe NIC but to where I am it is at least 2 weeks away.  Wifi works, as noted, but I'm trying to do some video work and the long latency 30-50mbps shared wifi link is pretty painful compared to gigabit copper.  Plus Synergy sucks over wifi.

If anyone has any clues, I'd be grateful.  The essential bits are:

```
$ uname -a
Linux dg-dl 5.8.0-34-generic #37~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 14:53:00 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 05
       serial: 50:65:f3:39:5b:03
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.8.7-NAPI duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 ip=192.168.100.17 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:26 memory:ef100000-ef11ffff memory:ef139000-ef139fff ioport:f040(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@3:1
       logical name: wlxaca2131ef18e
       serial: ac:a2:13:1e:f1:8e
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7601u driverversion=5.8.0-34-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.100.47 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11

$ modinfo e1000e | grep version
version:        3.8.7-NAPI
srcversion:     035BD57B8D93A45D1668FCC


$ lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM [8086:153a] (rev 05)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ethernet Connection I217-LM [103c:1906]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

$ dmesg | grep e1000e
[16807.605025] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.8.7-NAPI
[16807.605026] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2020 Intel Corporation.
[16807.605193] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[16807.697918] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 0000:00:19.0 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[16807.770728] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 50:65:f3:39:5b:03
[16807.770731] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[16807.770756] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[16807.773042] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
[16813.146515] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved the problem - installed a new network card.  It would have been quite annoying if this were a laptop with this horrible i217 NIC on the mobo, but as a SFF workstation, there was space for a better supported card.  I installed a Syba Dual Port Gig card ('cause why not two ports...) SD-PEX24041.  Works as expected, do not need to rely on the dubious (but far more reliable than intel's NIC) USB-WiFI interface.

```
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.100.49  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.100.255
        inet6 fe80::dc98:973e:fd70:58ce  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:13:3b:5a:e5:bd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 36297  bytes 4150450 (4.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 6  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 25729  bytes 1998990 (1.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and now

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM [8086:153a] (rev 05)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ethernet Connection I217-LM [103c:1906]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:0123]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:0123]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

go Realtek, boo Intel.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the e1000e kernel modules out of lib/modules, specifically

```
/lib/modules/5.8.0-34-generic/updates/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko
```

Then rebooted.  This is working, even DHCP.  :-)

I'm not sure why it didn't work with the default install.  IT appears to be a driver problem - 3.2.6k seems to be built into the kernel.  That's good because

- e1000e-3.8.4 at the [intel site](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817) won't compile.
- e1000e-3.8.7 at [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/files/e1000e%20stable/3.8.7/) ("Fixed compilation on latest kernels after changes in Linux OS API") compiles but didn't work for me.

Updating the info provided above:

```
 sudo lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 05
       serial: 50:65:f3:39:5b:03
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 ip=192.168.100.17 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:26 memory:ef100000-ef11ffff memory:ef139000-ef139fff ioport:f040(size=32)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@3:1
       logical name: wlxaca2131ef18e
       serial: ac:a2:13:1e:f1:8e
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7601u driverversion=5.8.0-36-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

(cheap wifi dongle is disabled, still have network datas!)

```
$ modinfo e1000e | grep version
version:        3.2.6-k
srcversion:     0E07DC95DBB1EAF587D0B9D

$ lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM [8086:153a] (rev 05)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ethernet Connection I217-LM [103c:1906]

$ dmesg | grep e1000e
[    1.235411] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    1.235412] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    1.235550] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.310701] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 0000:00:19.0 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[    1.379360] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 50:65:f3:39:5b:03
[    1.379362] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.379397] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    1.400975] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
[   21.124245] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
```

EDIT - updated to Kernel 5.8.0.40 and the network card failed exactly the same way, but the same fix did not work:

well... system update to kernel 5.8.0-40 and same problem again. 4 e1000e drivers in /usr/lib/modules at

```
/usr/lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e
/usr/lib/modules/5.8.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e
/usr/lib/modules/5.8.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e
/usr/lib/modules/5.8.0-34-generic/updates/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e
```

removed those as before, rebooted, but no luck this time.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM [8086:153a] (rev 05)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ethernet Connection I217-LM [103c:1906]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

$ modinfo e1000e
filename:       /lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko
modinfo: ERROR: could not get modinfo from 'e1000e': No such file or directory
```

so tried moving that one back, and

```
# modinfo e1000e | grep version
version:        3.2.6-k
srcversion:     0E07DC95DBB1EAF587D0B9D
```

This is the version that was working with kernel 5.8.0.34.
So I guess it is time for plan B: add-in network card, having to debug this every kernel update is a less optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

well... system update to kernel 5.8.0-40 and same problem again. 4 e1000e drivers in /usr/lib/modules at

```
/usr/lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e
/usr/lib/modules/5.8.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e
/usr/lib/modules/5.8.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e
/usr/lib/modules/5.8.0-34-generic/updates/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e
```

removed those as before, rebooted, but no luck this time.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM [8086:153a] (rev 05)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ethernet Connection I217-LM [103c:1906]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

$ modinfo e1000e
filename:       /lib/modules/5.8.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko
modinfo: ERROR: could not get modinfo from 'e1000e': No such file or directory
```

Moving the e1000e kernel module to the 5.8.0-40 directory did not resolve things :/

```
$ ifconfig
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::3bc8:75fd:5185:caaf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 50:65:f3:39:5b:03  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 221  bytes 34968 (34.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 62  bytes 10857 (10.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xef100000-ef120000  

(link "good" but will not connect pass datas)

$ modinfo e1000e | grep version
version:        3.2.6-k
srcversion:     0E07DC95DBB1EAF587D0B9D

(same as was working before)

$ lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM [8086:153a] (rev 05)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ethernet Connection I217-LM [103c:1906]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
```

So back to plan b, installing a PCI NIC and bypassing the mobo I217-LM.